# Which character encodings does Mobile Safari support?

Tags: mobile-safari

Which character encodings does Mobile Safari support?

I'd like a list that I can verify, if possible.

Is it a different list to Desktop Safari? 
(where they're listed as part of the View menu)

Comment: I don't think you will ever find a list.  I've not heard anyone report a standard encoding which is not supported when appropriately signaled in the charset= source code.  If you find one I'd be very interested.  There is no support for non-standard ascii encodings of Indic or other scripts which require a custom font to be installed.  Whether that includes legacy dingbat and symbol font ascii encodings I'm not sure.

Comment: A while ago (2010) Hebrew character encoding was not supported on iOS but was on Mac OS X. That is, old web pages that use character encoding ISO 8859-8. Pre-dating UTF-8. I need to look into whether that's different today.

Comment: Here is a simple test page in iso 8859-8 (logical order), seems to work.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/s/h8.html  (Shifted first line is just different css setting).

Comment: This page http://www.amusement-center.com/project/aiky/origin/papapa3/index.html uses charset=EUC_JP which is not recognised automatically by Safari.

Comment: None of my OS X browsers recognize it either, probably because of the author's hyphen typo:  It should be EUC-JP instead of EUC_JP.

Comment: I'll consult my list of bookmarks and see if I have more